# Set Alt+Tab to switch all Windows, instead of Grouped Windows

Tags: shortcut-keys, application-switcher

In Ubuntu, if I am running multiple windows of the same application and I want to chose one of them using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, I can't instantaneously do it.  The default behavior is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, then wait on the *grouped application icon*, and finally the grouped windows will appear from which I can choose (a window).

Instead of grouping windows, can I change the default behavior to show all opened windows of the same application using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain the exact behavior in the question, do one of the following.

### Using a GUI Application

1. Install `dconf-editor`
2. Open `dconf-editor`
3. Find: `org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings`
    [image: Screenshot to find keybindings]

   1. Remove default behavior: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

      *Instructions*
       Find: `switch-applications`
       Change:  **Use default value** = `false`
       Change:  `['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab']` to `['<Super>Tab']`
       [image: screenshot remove default behavior alt+tab]
   2. Remove default behavior:  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

      *Instructions*
       Find: `switch-applications-backward`
       Change:  **Use default value** = `false`
       Change: `['<Shift><Super>Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Tab']` **to** `['<Shift><Super>Tab']`
       [image: screenshot remove default behavior shift+alt+tab]
   3. Set new behavior: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

      *Instructions*
       Find:  `switch-windows`
       **Use default value** = `false`
       `''` to `['<Alt>Tab']`
       [image: screenshot set new alt+tab behavior]
   4. Set new behavior: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

      *Instructions*
        Find:  `switch-windows-backward`
        **Use default value** = `false`
        `''` to `['<Shift><Alt>Tab']`
        [image]
4. If you want `switch-windows` to work across `workspaces`, not just in the current `workspace`, you can also uncheck `org/gnome/shell/window-switcher/current-workspace-only`
5. Close dconf-editor
6. Older versions Gnome: *(unnecessary in Ubuntu 18.04)*, You may also need to restart Gnome shell.  To do this, first save any work and close all applications. Finally, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type <kbd>r</kbd> to restart Gnome.

#### Using shell

**First, list existing settings**, in case you want to revert.  This does nothing other than list values.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications  
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward  
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows  
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward
```

**Change to new behavior**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "['<Shift><Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward "['<Shift><Alt>Tab']"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *switch between two grouped windows* of the same application, e.g. Gnome Terminal, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (*backtick* or *grave accent*; the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>). Add <kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch in reverse, i.e., <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.

It may not be easy (it wasn't for me) to get used to it, but when you do, you'll find it a lot easier and better.

Comment: Yes this seems reasonable, I am just used to Windows. Thanks :)

Comment: I have an AZERTY keyboard. What is the alternative to Alt + ~?

Comment: @Oussema I edited the answer. the key combo is actually Alt +` (backtick, the key above Tab)

Comment: @Oussema If you have [the French AZERTY layout](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/KB_France.svg), use `Alt` + `²`