# prevent ALT-Tab from bringing all windows to the front

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, application-switcher

I'm using GNOME3 (under Ubuntu 16.04) and I actually like the <kbd>ALt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>; <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd>/<kbd>`</kbd> (key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>, varies regionally depending on the layout of the keyboard) bindings for switching between applications and windows of a specific application, respectively.

My concern is that <kbd>ALt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> will take *all* windows of one application to the front whereas all I usually want and expect is the topmost of the windows from that application. How can I get this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how the default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher, which is an *application* switcher works, and how Gnome developers currently intended it to work. As usual, it does not fit all use cases equally well. This is great for multi-window applications such as Gimp, or to bring a few open related terminal windows to the front, but less ideal if you want to switch between, say, your browser and a specific window of your file manager to upload a file by drag and drop.

There are a few options:

- [Develop the habit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747541/how-do-i-easily-switch-between-windows-rather-than-applications-with-alttab-in?rq=1) of using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> followed by <kbd>Key_above_tab</kbd> (<kbd>`</kbd> on querty keyboards) while you keep holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to select only the window you want. (Drawback: you have to do this each time switching back between two window, which is why Ubuntu developpers proposed at one time to only switch the last window on a fast <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
- Make more intensive use of work spaces, where these windows of a same applications that do not belong directly to the current job at hand are moved to other work spaces.  Alternatively, hide the windows you momentarily do not need (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>). (Drawbacks: may not be suit use cases where all windows actually belong to the same activity, but are not needed all at once; you need to "prepare", i.e think of/bother with shuffling different windows around on different work spaces or hide them.)
- Change the key binding of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> [to the Window switcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292405/set-alttab-to-switch-all-windows-instead-of-grouped-windows?rq=1) rather than the Application switcher. This gives you a more conventional switcher, allowing to switching between windows rather than between applications. You could then still have <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> bound to the Application switcher. (Drawback: too many window switcher to choose from, asking mental energy to decide how you are going to make your next switch).
- There are some extensions that change the Alt+Tab behavior so only one window of the target application is raised, e.g. [Alt Tab lift first window](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/878/alt-tab-list-first-window/) by cork (Gnome Shell 3.12 to 3.28) and [AltTab mod](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4007/alttab-mod/) by Leleat (Gnome Shell 3.36 and up)

Comment: Consider mentioning that <Alt>+< ` > is <Alt>+ key above <Tab>. The key above <Tab> is backtick/grave in US/UK QWERTY keyboards, but it's not universal.

Comment: In Ubuntu 23.10 default for Alt+Tab is switch windows and for Super+Tab is switch applications. When I click Super+1...Super+N it brings all the app windows for the favorite app forward, though.